# python-linkedin: dynamic use

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I want to scrape LinkedIn, mostly find basic information about people.
I'm trying to use the LinkedIn api, python-linkedin.
It's seems that I'm missing something. If I want to get my profile for instance then I need to:

```
from linkedin import linkedin

KEY = "XXXX"
SECRET = "XXXX"
RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'

PERMISSIONS = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share']
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(KEY, SECRET, RETURN_URL, PERMISSIONS)

# Open the link manually.  
print(authentication.authorization_url)

# And copy from the redirected url.
authentication.authorization_code = 'XXXX' 
access_token = authentication.get_access_token()
application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)
print(application.get_profile())
```

This way is very hard-coded and static. How can I do the same but dynamiclly?

Comment: You mention that you seem to be missing something in your code. What are you missing? Do you get an error? Can you post that error?

Comment: I don't get an error, I just don't want to open the link manually every time.

Comment: Once you have a logged in `application`, you don't need to login again - just keep calling methods on that object. As long as you aren't timed out, it should maintain your session.

Comment: But I still need to manually copy the authorization code in the beginning. This is the part that  I want to do dynamically through code.

Comment: You could use the config module, and save your KEY and SECRET in an .ini file?

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial\example\documentation?

Comment: Sure: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Comment: I'm sorry but how does it allow me to not open the authentication.authorization_url and copy the authorization_code manually every time I want to connect to the api?